Mirror adhesive for large wall panel mirrors
A large mirror panel, 8' by 3', is beginning to come off the wall, from a top corner, after 40 years. What's an appropriate adhesive to use or process for repairing this? Photos below. Thank you.



Mirro-mastic from Palmer Adhesives has been the goto product for this type of application.

And assuming it's supported from below, I'd consider adding a mirror retainer bracket to the top—looks like there's room.

Supplement your repair by getting more of the small cornice you have at the bottom of your crown molding, and replicating it along the top of the mirror. Nail and glue it to the ceiling while pressed tightly to the mirror.

Hopefully the bottom is supported. If not, do something similar down there that includes supporting the weight of the mirror. The glue behind the mirror then becomes secondary.
